# How do I test using SNAPSHOT and where do I put a <pluginRepository>?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I am attempting to run https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-hello with the command `mvn appengine:gcloud_app_run`. The appengine-maven-plugin makes use of the [gcloud command line tools](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/). However, at version 1.9.15 there is currently a bug that does not allow you to use `unix:\\\` Sockets as your `$DOCKER_HOST`. A patch has been written and I was asked to test it; the message is as follows.

```
Can you test 1.9.16-SNAPSHOT with

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
?
```

I did try putting the `<pluginRepositories>` as a direct child of the `<project>` level of my `pom.xml`; it seems to accept that although I still have errors when running `mvn appengine:gcloud_app_run`:

> [INFO]   File
>   "/home/stephen/google-cloud-sdk/lib/docker/docker/tls.py", line 41, in
>   **init** [INFO]     'Path to a certificate and key files must be provided' [INFO] docker.docker.errors.TLSParameterError: Path to a
>   certificate and key files must be provided through the client_config
>   param. TLS configurations should map the Docker CLI client
>   configurations. See http://docs.docker.com/examples/https/ for API
>   details. [ERROR] Error: gcloud app run exit code= 1

I then tried changing `<appengine.target.version>1.9.15</appengine.target.version>` in my `pom.xml` file to `1.9.16-SNAPSHOT` ; this time when running `mvn appengine:gcloud_app_run` I get:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hello: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.google.appengine.demos:hello:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact
>   com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.16-SNAPSHOT ->
>   [Help 1]

So, I have no idea what I am doing. Specifically, I don't know how to upgrade to SNAPSHOT or where I put this `<pluginRepositories>` thing. If you can resolve the problem I would really appreciate an explanation or link to what is going on here, as there is obviously some background knowledge that I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by just randomly trying things. Here is my pom.xml, the changed parts are the inclusion of `<pluginRepository>` and the string `1.9.15` was changed to `1.9.16-SNAPSHOT`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>com.google.appengine.demos</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <properties>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.15</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
          <webResources>
            <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
            <resource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```